# How can I absolute-position a child element relative to the content box (not padding box) of its relative-positioned parent?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

As you can see from the example below, .absolute_child is positioned relative to .relative_parent's padding box. How can I position it at the top of .relative_parent's content box instead? I'm willing to add extra elements (e.g. nested divs) to the HTML, as that generally seems to be what I wind up having to do for more fiddly layouts!

[image: Result]

```css
.relative_parent {
    position: relative;
    
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    
    background-color: green;
}

.absolute_child {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px; 
    
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative_parent">
    Content box of parent starts here
    <div class="absolute_child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the absolute child to be inside the parent div? If not, I would take it out.

Comment: instead of padding, use a transparent border